# blazor webassembly download file from api

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Webassembly ASP.NET Core hosted app, on the server I have a controler that returns a File, and on the Client I would like to have a button that when the user clicks on it download the file, How Can I achive this?

This is my Controller

```
[HttpGet("{reportName}")]
public FileResult GetReport(string reportName)
{
     var stream = _reportPrintRepository.Print(reportName);

     return File(stream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, reportName + ".pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to let the browser handle it:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@(Http.BaseAddress)YourController/Test1">download</a>
```

You get the base address from an inject HttpClient and make sure the URL matches the route you configured in the Controller.

Answer (score 3):

In order to download file you have to use Microsoft JSInterop.
There are many ways to implement your request.
One way that i use is get the file as byte array then convert to base64string.
Finally call the function that you created in javascript from server.

In server side

```
js.InvokeVoidAsync("jsOpenIntoNewTab",
                            filename,
                            Convert.ToBase64String(ReportPDF())
                            );
```

In client side in js file

```
function jsOpenIntoNewTab(filename, byteBase64) {
var blob = b64toBlob(byteBase64);

var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(blobURL);}
```

Comment: If you need more details about implementation do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much Baskovli, I try this too, and worked great.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-8.0